# Show $d_1$ is a metric on $C([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d_{1}$ be defined by $d_{1}: C\bigl([a,b]\bigr) \times C\bigl([a,b]\bigr) \to [0,\infty)$, where

$$d_{1}(f,g) = \int_{a}^{b}|f(x) - g(x)|~\mathrm dx.$$

Show $d_{1}$ is a metric on $C\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$. (ie: prove the three requirements for being a metric.)

Note that $C\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ is the set of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$.

A hint is given, but I think the question can be answered without it.

Here it is, anyway: if $d_{1}(f,g) = 0$, then $$d_{1}(f,g) = \int_{a}^{x}|f(t) - g(t)|~\mathrm dt = 0 \qquad\forall x \in[a,b].$$

My professors says in order to use that you must prove it.

Comment: You can use the hint + the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $f=g$ iff $d(f,g)=0$

Comment: There are the other requirements for being a metric as well. Were you able to see that $d_1$ fulfills those requirements? (Those are symmetry of $d_1$ and the triangle inequality)

Comment: I think the hint is useless. If $|f(x)-g(x)| >0$ at some point then there exist $\delta, \eta >0$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)| \geq \delta$ for $|y-x| <\eta$  and hence $d(f,g) >0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $d_1(f,g)=0$. Since the absolute value function is nonnegative, $$\int_a^x|f(t)-g(t)|\ dt \leq \int_a^b |f(t)-g(t)|\ dt =0,$$ for $x\in [a,b]$. This proves the hint.

By the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x|f(t)-g(t)|\ dt= |f(x)-g(x)| =0.$$ This implies that $f(x)=g(x)$ as desired.

The other requirements for a metric are straightforward so I assume you were able to them.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, the other two requirements were fairly simple, but it was the first one I was unsure about.